# Sorted and indexed WinForms ListBox items

Tags: c#, winforms

There is Client app with ListBox containing Records sorted by Record Time attribute. On application start Client loads Records from server and start listening to server updates. When server inform Client about new Record Client add Record to ListBox (theoretically with Time before last showed Recort Time). When Server inform about update or delete Client find message by ID and update or delete it (Theoretically when Time of Record is changed order of Records in ListBox must be changed).

I guess somethink like sorted dictionary with value time comparator is required.

```cs
public partial class RecordsForm : Form

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox recordsListBox;

    peivate SortedDictionary<long, Record> recordsDictionary;

    public RecordsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // this is not working because comparer must compare keys
        recordsDictionary = new SortedDictionary<long, Record>(new RecordComparer());
        var recordsBbinding = new BindingSource();
        recordsBbinding.DataSource = recordsDictionary;
        recordsListBox.DataSource = recordsBbinding;
    }

    public HandleCreateUpdate(Record record) 
    {
        recordsDictionary[record.Id] = record;
    }

    public HandleDelete(Record record) 
    {
        if (recordsDictionary.ContainsKey(record.Id))
        {
            recordsDictionary.Remove(record.Id);
        }
    }
}

class Record {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}

class RecordComparer : Comparer<Record>
{
    public override int Compare(Record left, Record right)
    {
        return left.Time.CompareTo(right.Time);
    }
}
```

Or exists another pattern used for something like this?

EDIT: Added screen

[image: List image]

List of Records is always sorted by Time desc. I want to synchronize this list across clients. When one edit/add/delete record other clients may reflects changes without reloading entire list or iterating over all items.

Comment: Please explain your comment "this is not working because comparer must compare keys". What do you mean by not working? Help us understand the specific problem/failure. ALSO: If you have a screenshot of how you want the `ListBox` to look (display member, columns etc.) when the binding is working can you add that to your question?

Comment: You probably want a [SortedBindingList<Record>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms993236(v=msdn.10))

Comment: Than you for replies. I added screenshot of ListBox @IVsoftware.

Comment: I will make some experiments with SortedBindingList<Record>, thank you @Jimi.